# c# static object reference

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static, log4net

I have a class like so

```
public class FileLogger
{
   public FileLogger(string typeOfLog)
   {
    //implementation
   }

   public void LogError(string err)
   {
    //implementation
   }

   public void LogMessage(string err)
   {
    //implementation
   }
}
```

Since this is a logging class for an application to log its output to a file, one would have expected it to be a static class. However as you can see it is not. It is however used in the application like this:

```
public class BugetApplication 
{
     private static FileLogger logger;

    //constructor
    public BugetApplicationClass()
    {
       logger = new FileLogger("some-constructor-parameter"); 
    }

    //a method that uses the FileLogger class for logging
    public string Classify()
    {
        try
        {
           //start multiple threads for classification
           Classification clsf = new Classification();
           clsf.handleEvent += clsf_handleEvent;
           clsf.Classify(); 
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
           logger.LogError(exp.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void clsf_handleEvent(string errString)
    {
       if(errString.Contains("error"))
       {
          logger.LogError(errString);
       }
    } 

}
```

Multiple threads are started by the BugetApplication class's classify method. Any errors in that class fire an event which is handled in the BugetApplication class's clsf_handleEvent method. So multiple threads could each fire their own event. Would creating the instance variable as a static variable in the BugetApplication class have any effect here or would keeping it non static have the same effect? I don't want any one thread to overwrite the error message of another thread.

**Edit**
Just to clear things out, the BugetApplication class which will be created only once has a static variable 'static FileLogger logger; '  it creates an instance once in its constructor, passing in some values to the constructor of the FileLogger class. In the BugetApplication class, there is a method which calls the Classification class's classify method. The Classify method starts the various threads and on any error fires an event which is handled back in the  BugetApplication class so this clsf_handleEvent method can have multiple calls on it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's `static` or not if you need thread synchronization

Comment: Thanks to `public BugetApplicationClass()` you create new logger instance every BugetApplication instance is created. Did you mean `static BugetApplicationClass()` - static ctor that is called only once?

Comment: What about a singleton that insure the log and one sheared instance of the logger?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil, singleton itself won't help, because the function can be called from multiple threads at the same time. Purpose of the singleton is to have a single instance of an object, but it doesn't solve multi-threading issues with concurrent access to external resources.

Comment: pwas: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it would overwrite the error message of another thread? The logger should just append the messages, so there shouldn't be any overwriting (depends how you handle the logging though). There is a potential problem however - depending on your logging function you might be blocking access to the file. Because the method works on an external file, you should probably use `lock` in the function.

It really doesn't matter if the class is static or not, the problem is concurrent access to external resources which needs to be synchronized for multiple threads to become thread-safe.

[lock documentation on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I am using log4net inthe FileLogger class and calling its method. Which function should have the lock and what should be locked?

Comment: log4net is thread-safe, so your code should be ok as is (unless you do something funky). if you weren't using thread-safe library, you'd have to lock the part in logger where you open the file and write to it

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the actual implementation of the logger.
Static classes are now frowned upon as they make unit testing more difficult. Many facilities which conventionally were implemented as static or singleton (loggers, e-mailers, etc.) now provide unit test/IoC friendly alternatives (e.g. a factory and an interface or virtual class).

The design of these facilities is usually a front end class which the client application uses to interact and an asynchronous back end which takes care of the synchronization and actual logging (or emailing, or whatever).

The crux is whether the front ends are multi-threaded or not.

If they are not; you should create a new one per thread. In this case the logger would probably have to be a local variable or parameter of the method using it.

Usually, however, they are multi-threaded and re-entrant, as all they do is pass along the log message to the back-end and have no state of their own. In this case they can be saved as a static variable or application wide singleton, but it is better to instantiate them in an IoC container as singleton and inject it to the classes using them. Doing so makes writing unit tests with mock loggers a lot easier.